# How to use useEffect to add and remove event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radix

I'm building RichText editor using Tiptap and one of my buttons is `preview` button. Once I click it, a modal with the preview appears. The content of this modal is an HTML coming from my editor. Additionally, once the modal appear, what I want to do is to add event listeners to specific parts of the preview. I'm trying to use `useEffect` with `open` as a dependency, but when it's called, the `ref` is empty and hence listeners are not added. Here is my code (using Shadcn for Modal):

```
type Props = {
  editor: Editor;
};

export const PreviewButton = ({ editor }: Props) => {
  let pathname = usePathname();
  let [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  let [lastContent, setLastContent] = useState(<div></div>);
  let ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  let handleClick = () => {
    console.log(pathname);
    setOpen(true);
    return true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let handleClick = () => console.log('Hi');
    // let content = document.getElementById('#preview') as HTMLDivElement;
    let content = ref.current!;
    if (open) content.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    return () => content?.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  }, [open]);

  let content = open ? (
    <div
      style={{ maxWidth: '800px' }}
      id='preview'
      className='ProseMirror prose dark:prose-invert'
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: editor.getHTML() }}
    ></div>
  ) : (
    lastContent
  );

  let onOpenChange = () => (open: boolean) => {
    open ? editor.setEditable(false) : editor.setEditable(true);
    !open && setLastContent(content);
  };

  let modalContent = (
    <DialogContent ref={ref}>
      <DialogHeader>
        <DialogTitle>Podgląd</DialogTitle>
      </DialogHeader>
      {content}
    </DialogContent>
  );

  return (
    <MenuButton
      icon={<PreviewIcon />}
      command={handleClick}
      tooltip={{
        content: <TooltipContent title={_t('commands.preview')} />,
      }}
      modal={{
        isModalButton: true,
        modalContent: modalContent,
        isOpen: open,
        setIsOpen: setOpen,
        onOpenChange: onOpenChange,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

I want to remove all listeners once the modal is closed and add them again once the modal is opened again because the content will be different. Adding `ref` to dependency array doesnt work as well